# Filter elements inside of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assuming that I have this multiple data and I need to filter set of elements.

How could I only filter the data with only `text` and `createdAt` will produce:

```
[
 createdAt: "2021-07-07",
 text: "No answer found."
]
```

Data:

```
var getMessage = [
  0: {
    status: 'SENT',
    type: 'text',
    createdAt: "2021-07-07T08:11:51.686Z",
    web: {
      message: {
        text: "Get Started"
      }
    }
  },

  1: {
    status: 'SENT',
    type: 'text',
    createdAt: "2021-07-07T08:11:53.547Z",
    web: {
      message: {
        text: "Etrt"
      }
    }
  },

  2: {
    status: 'SENT',
    type: 'text',
    createdAt: "2021-07-07T08:12:07.785Z",
    web: {
      message: {
        text: "No answer found."
      }
    }
  }

];

const findKeywords = "O"

const messageData = getMessage.map(x => x);
const findMessage = messageData.filter(x => x.web.message.text.toLowerCase().includes(findKeywords.toLowerCase()));

console.log(findMessage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get specific key value try this

```
const findMessage = messageData.filter(x => x.web.message.text.toLowerCase().includes(findKeywords.toLowerCase())).map(function (obj) {
    return {
        createdAt: obj.createdAt,
        text: obj.web.message.text
    };
});;

console.log(findMessage);
```